# Format Different Inputs with Different Styles

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, templates

I have a rails template form with this code:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
...
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Which in turn generates:

```
<div class="field">
<label for="item_title">Title</label><br />
<input id="item_title" name="item[title]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
...
<div class="actions">
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Item" />
</div>
```

I'm currently using this as part of a application.css:

```
input{
color:#000000;
padding:2px;
background-color:#F8F8F8;
border:1px solid #66CC00;
}
```

How can I style these to elements separately from the application.css file? I've tried `.text_field{#styles here}` and just `.field{#styles here}` in the file but with no luck.

I basically want them to look 'nice' but not have them so similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css attribute selector like this:

```
input[name=item\[title\]] {
    color: red;
}
```

To select input based on name, for example (if you have no class attribute avilable).

More info on [Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)

But, the thing you want, I guess, is:

```
.field input[type=text] {
    color: red;
}
```

or

```
.actions input[type=text] {
    color: red;
}
```

That is basics of css.

If you want more info about styling input elements, see [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095895/style-input-elements-css).

Comment: Thank you - the edit was what I was asking. I know it's the basics but thats the level i'm at! Thanks Again! :)

Comment: @CharlieEgan everyone were on basic level at some point, just try griving more precise question next time. You should understand, that Ruby is only server side HTML code generator, where HTML is just document data container language, and CSS is the way how to manage, how that data will be displayed.